# How to do real-time synchronization

Tags: oracle, synchronization, realm, firebird, real-time-data

I've an scenario where I have one database in Firebird or Oracle, and one database in sqlserver that it have some tables of the anothers databases.

I did like the tool like realm.io, where I can synchronize the databases.

How to do that?

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/

Comment: Just to confirm you want to sync tables in Oracle to SQLServer and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, want to sync tables in Oracle to SQLServer and vice versa.